# Merge has caused error saying I'm attempting to import runtime.js outside of src when the file structure hasn't changed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

All of the questions I have seen asked are people deliberately trying to import files from outside of their project. But I have done a merge from one branch to another which has caused no folder structure change and I am getting the error

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./src/App.jsx 1:40-132
>
> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/johnsmith/Documents/projects/prism/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
> You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

As you can see from the screenshot below my folder/file structure hasn't changed since doing npx create-react-app.

```
1: import './App.css';
```

Why am I getting this issue and are there any commands I can do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here.  There must be something wrong with react-refresh version `0.13.0`

We temporally fixed this forcing to install the `0.11.0` version:

```
npm i -D react-refresh@0.11.0
```

Comment: Fixed for me too

Answer (score 4):

The way I fixed this was by installing react-refresh. Then doing `npm ls react-refresh` to see what version was being used across the project. So then because the project/react-scripts etc was using 0.11.0 I had to change react-refresh from `"react-refresh": "^0.13.0",` to `"react-refresh": "^0.11.0",` in package.json, delete node_modules and package-lock.json, `npm install` then after that it all started working again.